# ejb deployment related

Tags: ejb

I am new to the world of EJBs and I am going thro HFEJB and EJB 3.1 (O'Reilly) books

HFEJB is bit old and concentrates much on J2EE 1.3 and in contrast EJB3.1 book is very new

So, during the learning of these books, I wanted to play around with some EJBs

Can anyone please tell me how to go for that (which server(glassfish/jboss etc) to use, sample deployment procedure) etc with EJB 3.1 in mind

Thanks in Advance

shiv

Answer (score 0, accepted):

using the eclipse with some of the ex from internet I was albe to achieve